# How to recover data from a partition with unknown filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount

I wanted to repartition my hard disk using KDE Partition Manager running from a USB. Unfortunately, something went wrong, as most of the partitions I wanted to delete are still present and the one I wanted to keep (but with larger size) has lost its filesystem information and, hence, it is unaccessible.

This is how it looks now `sda5`:

[image]

And that is `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 596,2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1549f232

Dispositiu Arrencada      Start      Final   Sectors   Size Id Tipus
/dev/sda1  *                 63  540619379 540619317 257,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2            1224201195 1250258624  26057430  12,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3             540619441 1224200012 683580572   326G  5 Estesa
/dev/sda5             540620863 1126558362 585937500 279,4G 83 Linux
```

If I want to change sda5 to its ext4 original filesystem, I get a warning stating that all changes will be lost.

Is there any way to recover original data or is it already lost for good?

**Edit:** as per @damadam request, this is the `lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 596,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 257,8G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  12,4G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 279,4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0    99M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 111,8G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  27,5G  0 part /
└─sdb6   8:22   0  93,1G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop1    7:1    0  86,6M  1 loop /snap/core/4650
loop2    7:2    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4830
```

Comment: the is a software "recuva" or something like that on windows that does that. so I believe surely that you can recover your old data. though it would be not as good as original. On ubuntu I have no idea but will search around

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/recover-deleted-files-linux/ , Take a look at this article

Comment: Your picture is about /dev/sda, but the fdisk output is only about /dev/sdb. Does it say nothing on /dev/sda?

Comment: @muclux you're right: I copied the wrong output. I have fixed it on the question.

Comment: @ccamara you can try to access on your partition by mounting it with `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /opt` and accessing it with `sudo chroot /opt`; if these 2 commands works, ping me because I can't ensure that you can restore your data like that

Comment: @damadam: after executing `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /opt` I get the following message: `mount: /dev/sda5 is already mounted or /opt busy` and I can't proceed with the next command as I get a message saying that  file or folder does not exist.

Comment: That was too easy, do you have any files inside `/opt`?

Comment: @ccamara can you add the output of `lsblk` at your question?

Comment: @damadam I have updated the question with your output request. As per your other question, yes /opt contains other folders, but all of them are specific software related and have nothing to do with the previous command.

Comment: can you try to mount it inside `/mnt`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80215/discussion-between-ccamara-and-damadam).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For further reference: Following @MaNyYaCk's advice, I have managed to recover the partition using [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

1. Download from https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download and uncompress
2. Locate the folder download on #1 and run command `sudo ./testdisk_static`
3. Click on create
   [image]
4. Navigate through the hard drive(s) and select the desired one and then the command `Proceed`.
5. Select the type of partitions, which in my case was `Intel` (usually makes a reasonable guess and selects it accordingly)
   [image]
6. Select the partitions you want to work with and then select `Analyse` command.
7. Select `Quick Search` command. After a while (it can take some time) it will find the partitions on that drive and you will see new options available.
8. Click on the new `write` option that appeared after #7 (if it is not available you may want to make a Deep search instead of a quick one). You will be asked to confirm that you want to write partition table.
   [image]
9. If everything goes as expected your partitions will be recovered and available again (it may require to reboot)

Comment: didn't worked for me